# Angularjs service typerror undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I have a service in coffeescript like so:

```
App.service 'CalculateService', ->
  @Calculate = (student) ->
    if student.type == 'MatureStudent'
      student.age + 10
    else
      student.age + 5
```

JS version

```
App.service('CalculateService', function() {
  return this.Calculate = function(student) {
    if (student.type === 'MatureStudent') {
      return student.age + 10;
    } else {
      return student.age + 5;
    }
  };
});
```

And a controller like so:

```
App.controller 'MarksCtrl', ($scope, $filter, CalculateService, lecture) ->

**create array**
$scope.students = []
angular.forEach $scope.lecture.students, (student) ->
    ......
  $scope.students.push(student)

**save array**
$scope.saveStudents = ->
    angular.forEach $scope.students, (student) ->
        student.points = CalculateService.Calculate(student)
```

JS version

```
App.controller('MarksCtrl', function($scope, $filter, CalculateService, lecture) {
  $scope.students = [];
  angular.forEach($scope.lecture.students, function(student) {
    return $scope.students.push(student);
  });
  return $scope.saveStudents = function() {
    return angular.forEach($scope.students, function(student) {
      return student.points = CalculateService.Calculate(student);
    });
  };
});
```

I keep getting "Typeerror undefined is not a function" at when I call the CalculateService.Calculate and I have no idea why.

I've tried this and it works:

```
$scope.saveStudents = ->
  angular.forEach $scope.students, (student) ->
    student.points = 2
```

So the problem only arises when I call the service. Any idea how I can make this work?

Comment: Didnt read your question well the first time... I dont use coffee script so hard to debug, but it seems to me like you are not returning anything in your service. you should return object where Calculate is function in that object

Comment: Should I add a javascript version of the code, Tom?

Comment: yeah that would help

Comment: Check the answer from PSL. You have "return this.Calculate" so you returning the function itself - name is not exposed to controller. SO to call the function you would simply call CalculateService() , but I dont think you can do taht with service, it would have to be factory. And actually this.Calculate() at the return point doesnt exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are returning the function itself as service. Instead just do not return the function, service gets newed up by the injector just attach the method to its instance and return nothing. In your original case you would have to invoke it as `CalculateService(student)`

Try:

```
App.service 'CalculateService', ->

  @Calculate = (student) ->
    if student.type == 'MatureStudent'
      student.age + 10
    else
      student.age + 5

  return
```

I have not used coffeescript, i used this [transpiler](http://js2.coffee/) to figure out what your service definition actually is. In times of doubts like these do a console logging of the service to see what it actually outputs (in your case you should see the function itself).

Comment: can you really return nothing in a service? If you declare the methond inside service you still have to expose it in returned object right?

Comment: @Tom That is coffee syntax, i used the converter to convert js back to coffee.

Comment: Yeah I just converted your script to JS< seems legit - didn't test it though

Comment: It works! I can't believe I spent 3 hours of my life over 6 characters. Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan.lay i personally do not like coffeescript (this necessity of explicit return is horrible :(), if you are just starting then i'd suggest TypeScript over it. After all angular 2.0 is also supporting TypeScript.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion PSL, I'll take a look at Typescript!

Answer (score 1):

Considering CoffeeScript automatically returns the last line of code, it is necessary to place a return statement at the bottom of the service

```
app.service 'CalculateService', ->
  @Calculate = (student) ->
    if student.type == 'MatureStudent'
      student.age + 10 
    else
      student.age + 5  

return
```

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/UUwFAV26KFou5sOOQelM?p=preview)